# Mongodb: find total number of zipcodes in a city, but also display the state of city

Tags: mongodb, zipcode

SQL equivalent -

`select state, city, count(distinct zip) from zipcodes group by state, city;`

Following works fine -

```
    db.zipcodes.aggregate( [ 

    { $group: { _id: { state: "$state", city: "$city", zipcode: "_id"}, zip: { $sum: 1 } } },

    { $group: {  _id: "$_id.city", zcount: {$sum: "$zip"}} },

    {$sort: {zcount: -1} }
 ] )
```

But I am unable to display the state of the city.
Kindly help.

Below is format of document `("_id" is the zipcode)`

```
    {
    "_id" : "01002",
    "city" : "CUSHMAN",
    "loc" : [
            -72.51565,
            42.377017
    ],
    "pop" : 36963,
    "state" : "MA"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your document?

Comment: it is in this format

{
        "_id" : "01002",
        "city" : "CUSHMAN",
        "loc" : [
                -72.51565,
                42.377017
        ],
        "pop" : 36963,
        "state" : "MA"
}

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29295300/edit) your post to add it. Don't post it here.

Comment: @Michael Must be 10gen's M101 homework :)

Comment: Why are you using two `$group` stages in your pipeline?

Comment: i learned it from the official website docs.mongodb,

Not sure if it is the right way

Answer (score 0):

`db.zipcodes.aggregate( [

        { $group: { _id: { state: "$state", city: "$city", z:"_id"}, total: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $group: {  _id: {state:"$_id.state", city:"$_id.city"}, count: {$sum: "$total"}} }  , 
        {$sort: {count: -1} }

 ] )`

Output - 

    `{ "_id" : { "state" : "PA", "city" : "PHILADELPHIA" }, "count" : 48 }
    { "_id" : { "state" : "IL", "city" : "CHICAGO" }, "count" : 47 }
    { "_id" : { "state" : "TX", "city" : "SAN ANTONIO" }, "count" : 45 }
    { "_id" : { "state" : "TX", "city" : "DALLAS" }, "count" : 44 }
    { "_id" : { "state" : "MO", "city" : "KANSAS CITY" }, "count" : 41 }`

The output for this looks good, but not sure if it is right